# get all images with xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get all image from u list in HTML with Hpple and xpath but no benefit

my HTML node like these

```
<ul id="week_slider">
      <div id="week_program_img">
            <img id="Img1" src="imageurl">    
      </div>
</ul>
```

but some times (img) tags be inside (a) tags like this

```
<a href="url">
       <img id="Img1" src="imageurl"> 
</a>
```

and I can get only the images (which not in 'a' tags) when put this path in xpath

```
//ul[@id='week_slider']//div[@id='week_program_img']
```

also I can get images (which in 'a' tags) when put this path in xpath

```
//ul[@id='week_slider']//div[@id='week_program_img']/a
```

but I want to get all of images in same time both of in or without  tags 
how can i do this in same xpath ?
i try use (or)  , (|) , (and) operators like this

```
//ul[@id='week_slider']//div[@id='week_program_img'] | //ul[@id='week_slider']//div[@id='week_program_img']/a
```

but it's not working fine

my full code :

> NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryStringimage1 =
>   @"//ul[@id='week_slider']//div[@id='week_program_img']";
>
> ```
> NSArray *newsNodesimage1 = [newsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryStringimage1];
>
>
>
>
> NSMutableArray *image1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
> for (TFHppleElement *element in newsNodesimage1) {
>
>
>
>     Tutorial *tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];
>     [image1 addObject:tutorial];
>
>     for (TFHppleElement *child in element.children) {
>         if ([child.tagName isEqualToString:@"img"]) {
>
>             tutorial.imageUrl = [child objectForKey:@"src"];
>         }
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: `//ul[@id='week_slider']//div[@id='week_program_img']//img` ?

Comment: How about `//img/@src` ?

Comment: thanks for reply , i try both //img and //img/@src  not get any images !

Comment: Do you use firebug fireXpath addon ? With `//img/@src` I found many images on the current page. Do you ?

Comment: no , i don't use it, but i just now install it , what i can do wiht fireXpath ?

Comment: Testing live in HTML/XML trees

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
//ul[@id='week_slider']//div[@id='week_program_img']//img
```

**Or in case you want to select the parent of every such image, which seems to be the case based on the provided XPath expressions, use**:

```
//ul[@id='week_slider']//div[@id='week_program_img']/descendant-or-self::*[img]
```

Comment: Nice :) second path was wonderful , and get all images. thanks so much Dimitre

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but here is another way:

```
//ul[@id='week_slider']//descendant::img
```

The nice thing is that descendant selects all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) of the current node. In this case, all images that exist in a `div` with `id='week_slider`.

You can also select images by index, i.e.

```
//descendant::img[1]
```

Comment: why is everyone using // in examples ?  i use this and it hides text like in php .