# Locating certain elements using xpath

Tags: html, css, xpath

I am building a web page scraper and need to grab certain elements of a web page. These elements do not have names/id's associated with them. Using Google Chrome developer I have copied to xpath to the elements and have tried to gather them that way with no results.

I have also tried numerous examples from the web with no results.
The methods that are being used are either SelectSingleNode or SelectNodes.

The path to one element is: `/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/a/img`

How can I grab these unnamed elements?

Comment: Can you share that html code section for which you are trying to get xpath?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The path is listed. I am trying to find the img elements

Comment: Yes but is that correct path? or you are trying to find correct one?

Comment: Yes its correct, verified with chrome developer. Isn't it possible to grab all of a certain type of element.. somthing like(".//*img") Looking at MSDN XPATH examples it leads me to believe you can, but all attempts have failed

Comment: Check if this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627216/get-all-images-with-xpath

Comment: those suggestions don't work either.

Comment: @DoImagine `.//*img` is not a valid xpath expression, but `//img` is valid. Some elements are generated on client-side (browser executing js, etc), so what you see in browser is not necessarily exactly the same as what you get from accessing the url some other ways

Comment: @DoImagine what parser do you use here? HtmlAgilityPack or something?